# C++ thread exit loop condition

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, loops, condition-variable

I want to create a counter inside a thread, and stop it by changing the value of a boolean.

Here's my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

bool _terminateT;
mutex mtx;
condition_variable cv;

void counter()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
    int i(0);

    while(!_terminateT)
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
        i++;
        cv.wait(lock);
    }
}

int main()
{
    _terminateT = false;
    thread t(counter);

    sleep(4);
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lckg(mtx);
        _terminateT = true;
    }

    cv.notify_one();

    cout<<"main"<<endl;
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the loop is blocked by the `wait` function.
Is there a way to protect the `_terminateT` variable without blocking the while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that code you don't need condition variable. A mutex protecting the boolean variable would be enough. It should be locked and unlocked in loop check.

In fact, in that particular example where there is no risk of data race (you are just setting variable from 0 to other value once), you could even skip the mutex and set variable in an unprotected manner - the loop will always terminate, as even if thread runs on other core than main function, its cache will get the correct changed value eventually. Situation would be different if you shared other data between threads.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply!! But what would happen if I changed the value of the variable while its value is checked by the loop? Wouldn't the variable be read and set at the same time?

Comment: That's not possible. From this perspective processors work in atomic way, and (huge oversimplification!) they do one thing at the time. If situation was different and your variable was something else than changing 0 to non-0, like changing 0000000000000000 to 123456789ABCDF01 a data race may occur when one CPU core is writing and other is reading. This could result in the reader seeing value as 1234567800000000 - so half updated. You can read about "cache coherence" and MESI, but it's quite complicated :) But processor doesn't "break", just reader thread reads bogus data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!